# SSRS Report Subscription Data Filter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working on a SSRS report that I will be subscribing through an email which should render as MHTML. However, many times, the report has too many records, which leads to the following error - Exceeds Max MIME Parts Per Message. So, is it possible to restrict number of rows or pages that I can send through the report via an email. I don't see any option for the restriction.
[image]

Comment: You can only restrict the number of rows in the report.. not at subscription time. I'd create another hidden report which returns only a maximum of X records and use that for the email subscription. But woudln't restricting the number of rows make the report incomplete? why does it need to me MHTML?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an option to restrict the number of records for a subscription so why don't you create one?

Create a parameter called LIMIT with a Yes/No selection and default to NO. For your subscription, set the LIMIT parameter value to YES.

Add a Filter to your Dataset based on your parameter.

[image]

For the Expression, you need a unique value - whether it's an ID field or combination of fields. Equal values will only be counted ONCE.

For the Value expression, if the LIMIT is **Yes** then use the number of records that will fit in the email. For the else, use a large number - more than you would ever expect in the report.

```
=IIF(Parameters!LIMIT.Value = "Yes", 100, 1000000)
```

[MS Docs - Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/filter-equation-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)